# Compare XML Node Values using Name Tag and Remove the Tag

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the XML Example

```
<order>
 <orderItem>
    <OrderId>Ex1</OrderId>
    <amount>100</amount>
 </orderItem>
 <orderItem>
    <OrderId>Ex2</OrderId>
    <amount>150</amount>
 </orderItem>
 <orderItem>
    <OrderId>Ex1</OrderId>
    <amount>250</amount>
 </orderItem>
</order>
```

If the OrderId tag value is Equal to another OrderId tag value then add the Amount Tag and remove the newly added tag.

The Result Output i need should be like below

```
<order>
 <orderItem>
  <OrderId>Ex1</OrderId>
  <amount>350</amount>
 </orderItem>
 <orderItem>
  <OrderId>Ex2</OrderId>
  <amount>150</amount>
 </orderItem>
</order>
```

The OrderId value should be Changed.

```
string filename = "File Location";
var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var results = doc.Descendants("order");
var orderItemcount = results.Descendants("orderItem").Count();
```

I don't know what to do next.

Thanks in Advance.

**UPDATE** :

My New XML Like Below

```
<order>
 <orderItem>
   <Orders>
     <OrderId>Ex1</OrderId>
     <amount>100</amount>
   </Orders>
 </orderItem>
 <orderItem>
  <Orders>
   <OrderId>Ex2</OrderId>
   <amount>150</amount>
  </Orders>
 </orderItem>
 <orderItem>
  <Orders>
    <OrderId>Ex1</OrderId>
    <amount>250</amount>
  </Orders>
</orderItem>
</order>
```

If the OrderId is Same then Add that OrderItem tag to the Matching Tag.
The Result i need to be Like below

```
<order>
 <orderItem>
  <Orders>
    <OrderId>Ex1</OrderId>
    <amount>100</amount>
  </Orders>
  <Orders>
   <OrderId>Ex1</OrderId>
   <amount>250</amount>
 </orderItem>
 <orderItem>
  <Orders>
   <OrderId>Ex2</OrderId>
   <amount>150</amount>
  <Orders>
 </orderItem> 
</order>
```

**Update Answer**

```
var groups = doc.Descendants("order").Descendants("orderItem").Descendants("Orders")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("OrderId"))
                .ToList();


            XElement newXml = new XElement("order");
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                newXml.Add(new XElement("OrderList", new object[] {
                // new XAttribute("OrderId", group.Key), // If you Need Key for Attribute add this.
                    group
            }));
            }
```

Comment: Simply group your `orderItems` by `OrderId` and sum up the `amount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps:

1. Group your orders together by id, and then for each grouping...
2. Get the total amount
3. Set the first order amount to the total
4. Remove the remaining orders

The code is fairly straightforward:

```
var ordersById = doc.Descendants("orderItem")
    .GroupBy(x => (string) x.Element("OrderId")); // 1

foreach (var grouping in ordersById)
{
    var total = grouping
        .Sum(x => (decimal) x.Element("amount")); // 2

    grouping.First().SetElementValue("amount", total); // 3

    grouping.Skip(1).Remove(); // 4
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/178Kpo) for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a standard group by `OrderId` with `Sum(amount)` transformation, which can be accomplished by the following LINQ to XML query:

```
var output =
    from order in doc.Descendants("order")
    select new XElement("order", 
        from orderItem in doc.Descendants("orderItem")
        group orderItem by (string)orderItem.Element("OrderId") into orderItems
        select new XElement("orderItem",
            new XElement("OrderId", orderItems.Key),
            new XElement("amount", orderItems.Sum(e => (int)e.Element("amount")))));
```

Comment: May i know what variable is e?

Comment: `orderItems` type is `IGrouping<string, XElement>`, which in turn is `IEnumerable<XElement>`, so `e` type is `XElement`. The `orderItems` contains a collection of `XElement` s that share the same key ("OrderId" in your case)

Comment: Ok Thank You, Will Check.

Comment: Can You Please Saw my Updated Question and help me to solve.

Comment: Sure I or someone else can help you. But I would suggest you posting the new requirement as a new question, because the "update" basically invalidates all the current answers, which is against the site rules.

Comment: In meantime I solve that Issue too. I will post the answer. Thanks for your Reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var groups = doc.Descendants("orderItem")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("OrderId"))
                .Select(x => x.Select(y => new {orderId = y, amount = (int)y.Element("amount")}))
                .ToList();
            for (int groupNum = groups.Count - 1; groupNum >= 0; groupNum--)
            {
                var group = groups[groupNum];
                int total = group.Select(x => x.amount).Sum();
                for (int orderItemCount = group.Count() - 1; orderItemCount >= 0; orderItemCount--)
                {
                    var orderItem = group.Skip(orderItemCount).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (orderItemCount > 0)
                    {
                        orderItem.orderId.Remove();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        XElement amount = orderItem.orderId.Element("amount");
                        amount.Value = total.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```